# Angular EventEmitter returning undefined object

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working on a project for school and I've hit a wall with my inexperience with Angular. I've got a left-nav component with a bunch of checkbox selections, and when a user selects one of the "codes" an API call goes off to our data store to retrieve all the values for a given "key"

```
this.dataService.getData(key);
```

From that point I've got a different component  which is listening for the retrieval of the data and will then make a graph. 
The problem I'm facing is the data service is successfully making the API call and getting back a JSON response but I cannot figure out how to pass that data/object over to the time-graph.

```
private segResponse$: Observable<SegmentResponse>;    
@Output() dataRetrieved: EventEmitter<Observable<SegmentResponse>> = new EventEmitter();
    ...
getData(key: string) {
    this.segResponse$ = this.httpClient.get<SegmentResponse>(this.baseUrl + key);
    console.log('seg resp in service ' + this.segResponse$);
    this.dataRetrieved.next(this.segResponse$);
}
```

I can see the console response just fine here but in my time-graph, the object (of type SegmentResponse) is undefined. "state" is just one of the properties (string) of SegmentResponse.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.dataService.dataRetrieved.subscribe( data => {
  this.segResponse = data;
  console.log('time graph got data ' + this.segResponse.state);
  });
}
```

So why is it undefined in the first place? What do I need to do to get the SegmentReponse from the data service successfully over to time-graph?
I'm guessing the .next part is not waiting for the successful return of the httpClinet.get but like I said, I'm at the edge of my knowledge of Angular + search-fu ability to find the right words go look up to get a solution.

Answer (score 0):

httpClient.get returns an Observable. You need to subscribe to it.

```
getData(key: string) {
    this.segResponse$ = this.httpClient.get<SegmentResponse>(this.baseUrl + key).subscribe((response) => {
        console.log('seg resp in service ' + response);
        this.dataRetrieved.next(response);
    });
}
```